# SQL SSRS very large extract

Tags: sql, reporting-services, extract

I support some very large databases (approaching a terabyte). We currently have an in-house reporting solution, but are investigating the use of `SSRS` (`SQL Reporting Services`). However our users sometimes need to extract large volumes of data (many millions of records), which may take a few hours to retrieve.

What is an advisable approach to dealing with such large volumes?

> Note. Getting the business to redefine there need for such large
>   extracts is not currently an option.

Comment: Unfortunately if you want to make an omlette you have to break a few eggs, but if you are using sql server you can look at providing views that streamline the access of these large recordsets. The classics, like indexing can work wonders. When you have long running queries it is always worth a look at how much performance enhancement you could achieve in the time it takes the extract to run. We'd need to know more about what sort of structure is being queried to tell you more.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting millions of records at the time... are we talking about reporting or analytic? Do they browse through those records, or aggregate over them? If you have lots of aggregation over millions of rows, you may consider SSAS cubes which would store pre-calculated aggregations, and then point reporting to cubes. SSAS server "listens" to the underlying DW/database and updates aggregations periodically (settable).